# Hydra shows 1 valid password found but shows password as wordlist location

Tags: hydra

When I use hydra to crack a router's password, it shows that 1 valid password found but shows the location of my wordlist as the password.

That IP is not mine, I got it from shodan.io. I wanted to practice but I have no router.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please do not post images of text - copy/paste the text and use the code formatting tools

Answer (score 2):

Note that trying to attack a random device you found on Shodan is very likely illegal, and by providing this answer, I do not condone or support any illegal activities. Instead, I highly suggest that you set up your own target in a virtual machine instead; I'm not sure why you need a router for this.

There are likely two problems with your usage of Hydra.

First, from the Hydra man page (`man hydra`):

> -p PASS or -P FILE
>
> try password PASS, or load several passwords from
>   FILE

You used `-p` which uses the argument as password, where you need to use `-P` instead to load from a file.

Second, your choice of the `http-get` module may be invalid for the target. Looking at Hydra's source code, `http-get` will use HTTP basic authentication by default. If the target web server does not use basic authentication and returns a non-error HTTP status code (e.g. 200 OK) when Hydra attempts authentication, Hydra will think that the authentication was successful. It's also possible that while no authentication exists on '/', another path may require it.

Instead of basic authentication, the target may use some kind of HTTP form login, where the `http-{get,post}-form` methods may be more appropriate.